# Laravel Vapor not using with the updated build

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I'm deploying a Laravel app to Vapor and cache is automatically deleted right after the deploy. I also clear it manually via CLI just to be sure. Still, it's not running with the updated build because it can't find a Class that instead it's there (double checked the namespaces and everything else). On my local machine it's working fine, the class is found and so I can instantiate it.

I tried to clear every possible cache (route, config, view, also run a composer dump-autoload) but nothing seems to work. Any clue?

Comment: Have you double-checked the capitalization? Lambda's filesystem is case sensitive; Windows-based developers often run into this. `app/Class.php` must be `App\Class`, not `App\class`. `app/class.php` would have to be `App\class`. etc.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I checked this and there are not naming problems, i copied the path that is giving the error and using it as search term in project with case sensitive turned on, so: Class 'App\NovaTool\Sisteract\SisteractRest\RicercaElencoImmobiliSoggetto' not found but I can actually find this in my project